# MongoDB remove outer brackets from result

Tags: mongodb

Not sure why I'm not getting this... I just want to return the results without the outer brackets, which I've done before fine, but the way my last stage is grouping, it sets up the results in a way that gives errors with $mergeObjects (error: input is an array) and $concatArrays (input is an object).

Pipeline:

```
User.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: userId
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'clients',
        localField: "clients",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "Clients",
        pipeline: [
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              fullName: "$fullName",
              contracts: {$last: "$contracts"}
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              fullName: 1,
              contracts: {
                type: "$contracts.contType",
                hours: "$contracts.contHours"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "visits",
        localField: "visits",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "Visits",
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $and: [
                {visitStart: {$gte: new Date(start)}},
                {visitEnd: {$lte: new Date(end)}}
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              client: "$client",
              hours: "$totalHours",
              month: {
                "$month": "$visitEnd"
              },
              year: {
                "$year": "$visitEnd"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              client: 1,
              hours: 1,
              date: {
                $concat: [
                  {
                    $substr: [
                      "$year",
                      0,
                      4
                    ]
                  },
                  "-",
                  {
                    $substr: [
                      "$month",
                      0,
                      2
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: {
                date: "$date",
                client: "$client"
                // hours: "$hours"
              },
              hoursCount: {
                $sum: "$hours"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: "$_id.client",
              hours: {
                $push: {
                  date: "$_id.date",
                  count: "$hoursCount"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 0,
              client: "$_id",
              hours: {
                $sortArray: {input: "$hours", sortBy: {date: 1}}
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        "Clients": 1,
        "Visits": 1
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        result: {
          $map: {
            input: "$Clients",
            as: "client",
            in: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$$client",
                {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$Visits",
                        as: "visits",
                        cond: { $eq: ["$$visits.client", "$$client._id"]}
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        } 
      }
    },
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "result": [
            {
                "_id": "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
                "fullName": "Johnny Cochrane",
                "contracts": {
                    "type": "Quarterly",
                    "hours": 120
                },
                "client": "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
                "hours": [
                    {
                        "date": "2023-4",
                        "count": 5.51
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2023-5",
                        "count": 6
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2023-6",
                        "count": 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e",
                "fullName": "Sheila Thompson",
                "contracts": {
                    "type": "Quarterly",
                    "hours": 140
                },
                "client": "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e",
                "hours": [
                    {
                        "date": "2023-4",
                        "count": 5.5
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2023-5",
                        "count": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2023-6",
                        "count": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried various options around a final stage like this, but cannot seem to get it right:

```
{
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$$ROOT",
            "$result"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Ideally I'd just have the actual data array like so:

```
[
            {
                "_id": "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
                "fullName": "Johnny Cochrane",
                "contracts": {
                    "type": "Quarterly",
                    "hours": 120
                },
                "client": "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
                "hours": [
                    {
                        "date": "2023-4",
                        "count": 5.51
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2023-5",
                        "count": 6
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2023-6",
                        "count": 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e",
                "fullName": "Sheila Thompson",
                "contracts": {
                    "type": "Quarterly",
                    "hours": 140
                },
                "client": "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e",
                "hours": [
                    {
                        "date": "2023-4",
                        "count": 5.5
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2023-5",
                        "count": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2023-6",
                        "count": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what I wasn't getting, but needed to $unwind "$result" - turned the array to object, then $replaceRoot. For some reason I had thought I did that... maybe just moving too fast.

```
{
      $unwind: "$result"
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot:  "$result"        
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.pop()` it.

```js
let a = ["test"];
let b = a.pop()

console.log(b)
```